# AntD Disabled component - is there a way to remove the red error on hover

Tags: antd, styling

I am trying to override the style for antd autocomplete component. If the component is disabled I would like to change the cursor to be default on hover rather than antd red icon.

I am using styled components so I know I will have to override ant classes directly. This is currently what I have tried to no avail.

```
&.ant-select-disabled {
            cursor: default !important;
        }
```

Update***

I have found the class that should be changed and if I change it in inspect it gives the expected behavior but adding it in the styled components does not do anything on re-render.

```
.ant-select-disabled.ant-select:not(.ant-select-customize-input) .ant-select-selector input {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly catch the element with CSS rules; this would be the relevant rule to apply:

```
.ant-select-disabled.ant-select:not(.ant-select-customize-input) .ant-select-selector {
  cursor: default !important;
}
```